# Is there a way to export filtered data from a grid in Sylius?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to export filtered data from a grid in the back-office to an Excel sheet. I didn't find any details on how to achieve such a thing in the documentation.

Did anyone do something similar? Is there a way to export filtered data from a grid in Sylius?

Answer (score 1):

It might be interesting to use the [Import/Export plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfSylius/SyliusImportExportPlugin). This plugin allows you to export what you have filtered on the grid out of the box for specific entities. If your entity is not yet supported, there are plenty of examples on how to add support.

Answer (score 0):

Very broad question… Not possible out of the box, you have to do this by yourself:

1. Custom controller (eg. `ExportController`) in which you load the grid
2. Pass query params to filter the grid using AJAX, along with additional parameters like:

   1. The grid you want to load
   2. Desired format type (eg. `JSON`, `XML`, `PDF`)
   3. Maybe some specific layout settings (eg. col&row count in case of PDF)
3. Get the result as array and convert to the desired format
4. Store result in a file and return that as a binary response to the user